# Promise sends resolve before the process finish

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, download, promise, request

everybody,
I have a project, that asks user to where their target URL for download images and compress them. After I ask user URL, the process downloads images into a directory one by one asynchronously but, after all files download i send `resolve` in this Promise. The `resolve` is faster than my creating file (download) process with miliseconds. How can I send `resolve` after the all entire download process end?

```
const download = (uri, filename, callback) => {
    request.head(uri, (err, res, body) => {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
    });
};

const downloadImages = (target, inputPath) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resource(target)
            .then(res => {
                let count = 0;
                for(let obj in res) {
                    download(res[obj].request.request.url, path.join(path.parse(inputPath).dir, path.parse(url.parse(res[obj].request.request.url).pathname).base), (err) => {
                        if(err) reject(err);
                        console.log(`${path.parse(url.parse(res[obj].request.request.url).pathname).base} file created!`);
                        count++;
                        console.log(count);
                    });
                };
                resolve(true);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
};

const compressImages = (inputPath, outputPath, target) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        downloadImages(target, inputPath)
            .then(res => {
                if(res === true) {
                    console.log('succeed!');
                };
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject(err);
            });
    });
};

compressImages('lib/img/*', 'lib/cimg/', 'https://webmedya.com.tr').then(res => {
    if(res === true) console.log('got it!!!')
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And the result of this process is:

```
succeed!
got it!!!!!!!!
*after a 10-25 miliseconds*
webmedya-logo.png file created!
1
google-ajansi-ankara.jpg file created!
2
google-ile-zirveye.png file created!
3
adwords-reklam.png file created!
4
youtube-reklam-logo.png file created!
5
```

Comment: where are you calling resolve? Cannot find in your code

Comment: Oh, wow! Too sorry, I added it after for...in loop, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please try editing your for loop, by adding an IIFE and a counter? Something like:

```
for (let obj in res) {
  (function (obj, res) {
    download(..params, (err) => {

    });
  })(res, obj)
};
```

Ideally, its recommended that you do not use a combination of callbacks-promises.

If you are planning on using promises only, try using [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird), and for callbacks [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) might help!

Hope this helps!

Comment: How about to add `counter`? I made only this:
            `for(let obj in res) {
                    ((obj, res) => {
                        download(res[obj].request.request.url, filename)
                            .then(() => {
                                console.log(`${filename} created!`);
                                count++;
                                console.log(count);
                            })
                            .catch(err => {
                                reject(err);
                            });
                    })(obj, res); };`

Comment: Hi @n3pixowe, adding an IIFE will help your methods maintain state while executing. Thus, to run this you need to keep track using a counter add this inside your 'download' callback: `count++; if (Object.keys(res).length === count) { return resolve(true); }`

Comment: You just damaged my brain! Thanks for the solution bro! You are very good :)

Comment: Sure, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Since your `download` function is a asynchronous callback, `resolve` does not wait until callbacks are called inside `download`. Maybe wrapping `download` by a promise and calling a `Promise.All` a made array by for loop do the trick.

Comment: How to change `for...in` function with `Promise.all()` function? Can you please help me about it?

Comment: what is the request module?

Comment: It just makes request with streaming pipe in this project.

Comment: can it return a promise?

Comment: Yes, it can return a promise. But the other solution post guy solve the problem. Thanks for you for looking at my problem, thanks so much to you too :)

Comment: great. no problem